# How to use jquery noConflict without changing third party library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use some library provided by our third party written in jquery.we end up having conflicts with $ sign within our codebase once i try to incorporate jquery. i was able to resolve the conflict by creating an alias for $ sign and then update the $ sign with alias within third party library as well. Since it's a code written by third part and i am not very familiar with jquery i would prefer to find a workaround which does not involve updating the third party code itself. I also have an inlinne javascript (also provided by third party) that needs to get fired on the page itself.Any ideas how can i do this? below is the example of jquery files i am using:

```
<!-- jquery libs -->
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- third party library using jquery code-->
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqueryTest.js"></script>

<!-- inline javascript that gets fired on the page itself -->
 <script>
  $('#formvalue').jqueryTest({
   subdomain: 'xyz',
   selectData: function (data) {
   $('#formvalue').val(data.value);
   $('#form').submit();
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: What other library is conflicting with jQuery's `$` ? In your post it sounds like it's all jQuery, which wouldn't cause any conflicts.

Comment: hi azium, i am using lot of other libraries and it would've been complicated to paste the code here hence i pasted how i am including jquery only.

Answer (score 3):

This way you can code :

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq("button").click(function(){
        jq("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
    });
});
```

For more learning please refer following link 
http://alexmarandon.com/articles/widget-jquery-plugins/

Hope It helps :)

Comment: hi troubleshooter. this is what i did and worked as well. but with this approach i will need to update $ sign within the third party lib too which i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a right approach to edit third party libs, because it's not maintainable.

See this code from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/:

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $.noConflict();
    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Try this:

```
<!-- jquery libs -->
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- third party library using jquery code-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqueryTest.js">    </script>

<!-- inline javascript that gets fired on the page itself  <script>
$.noConflict();
$('#formvalue').jqueryTest({
    subdomain: 'xyz',
    selectData: function (data) {
        $('#formvalue').val(data.value);
        $('#form').submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

(You missed a } in your code).

Comment: Thanks and i agree i should not be updating third party lib. do i need to add $.noConflict() within the jqueryTest.js as well? how do i make sure that i do not have any $ conflicts from third party lib?

Comment: Check the first example. Where you start using third party, add noConflict before. That's enough.